# Windows 7 backup produces 0x80070002

Tags: windows-7, backup, windows-7-backup

I have a problem with my Windows 7 backup. It shows me the following error:

> Check your backup
>
> The system cannot find the file specified
>
> Backup time: 8/7/2011 15:53
> Backup location: Local Disk (E:)
> Error Code: 0x80070002

I can still backup a complete system image. But when I select certain folders the file not found error is thrown. I already tried to find the faulty files per binary search but there seem to be several faulty regions.

Is there a way to get a better errror message (at least with a file path) or a way to skip these files and print their location?

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 7 errors, look in Events log. It could provide a file location for you. After that, you can run a System File Checker (SFC) and/or an error check on the drive.

1. [sfc-System file check](http://support.Microsoft.com/kb/929833)
2. [Check-a-drive-for-errors](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Check-a-drive-for-errors)

I have Windows 7 and I found [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/filecab/archive/2008/03/12/common-causes-and-solutions-to-backup-system-restore-and-complete-PC-backup-problems-updated.aspx) on a Microsoft Vista Backup blog (it lists the user settings Vista should have).

I checked in my registry (Windows 7) and I had all the settings that the Vista blog said Vista should have. They may not have changed this part of the system. This workaround basically gets you to delete the current profile and run a backup to reset it.

Registry is important and changes can damage your system etc, etc - so backup the registry first.

I could not find a Windows 7 only solution but Windows 7 and Vista are often found with the same errors and fixes.

Comment: The event log doesn't contain new information, registry seems okay (all profiles and paths correct) and SFC doesn't find anything. I'll check the drive next.

Comment: Thanks for your tips but nothing seems to work for me ...

Comment: @kasten-are the files you after in a library ?

Comment: No it's a folder on my mainpartition C:

Answer (score 0):

> Scenario 3:
>   Windows Backup will fail with error code 0x80070002, "The system cannot find the file specified." In this scenario, either of the following issues occurs:
>   The computer stops responding.
>   The copy operation stops.

.

> Cause:
>   Scenario 3 cause
>   This issue occurs if the following conditions are true:
>
> The computer has an NVIDIA USB Enhanced Host Controller Interface (EHCI) chipset.
>
> The computer has at least 4 GB of RAM.
>   You try to copy data from the computer to an external USB storage device.
>
> Notes
>
> This issue may also occur when you are using USB devices other than storage devices.
>
> This issue may also occur if you perform other input/output (I/O) operations on the USB storage device. In this situation, the I/O operations fail.

[Source of Information](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/979281)

Comment: Thanks for your tip. The target is a harddrive connected per sata but i will try the patch anyway and report back.

Comment: "The update is not applicable to your computer" using the 64bit patch for my 64bit installation. Strange...

Comment: You must not have the Nvidia chipset it is targeted for.

Comment: Run a chkdsk /r on the hard drive.

Comment: Done runing chkdsk /r /f on the source and target disk. Still the same error :(